# How should I pause a rotation when my character collides with a gameObject?

Tags: unityscript

My character always moves forward and when he enters a turn(Trigger) this is what happens:

```
if(other.CompareTag("TurnLeft"))
{
    // Rotates the character in 90 degrees in 6 seconds.
    MoveObject.use.Rotation(transform, Vector3.down * 90.0, 6);
}
```

But when he contacts with the ("StageColliders"), he keeps rotating, even though he doesn't change his position. I practically need him to pause rotating when he hits ("StageColliders") and continue when he's free of collision.
Something like this would be ideal.

```
if(other.CompareTag("StageColliders"))
{
    // Pause the rotation above.
}
```

I found the MoveObject script here http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=MoveObject
in case someone's curious.

Comment: As for why it continues to rotate, I imagine you're stacking rotations, since every time the frame updates, you're triggering `.use.Rotation`, might want to limit it to one rotation.

Comment: I use as a trigger a plane, so I suppose it triggers only once. I'm not really sure about this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a pause to the code you've copied. Add some booleans to the top (sorry I don't do UnityScript, so syntax may be poor/inaccurate).

```
static var pauseRotation : Boolean;
static var pauseTranslation : Boolean;
```

And use these inside the while loops of the Translation and Rotation methods. For example, inside the Rotation method:

```
while (t < 1.0) {
    if(!pauseRotation) {
        t += Time.deltaTime * rate;
        thisTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(startRotation, endRotation, t);
    }
    yield;
}
```

Then create methods for setting the pause:

```
function SetRotationPause(setPauseRotation : Boolean) {
    pauseRotation = setPauseRotation;
}
```

And create a similar one for movement.